# Magento 2 Save customer attribute value while customer register

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, customer-attribute, plugin

I have created one 'test' text customer attribute. I have added input field on frontend customer register form. I can able to save this attribute value by override **createPost.php** from my custom module.

But I think this is not proper way to save value by override controller. There is any way to save customer attribute using plugin or observer?

Comment: Please share your observer code

Comment: Right now i have no observer code i have done it with override createpost controller

Comment: You have mentioned that "I have also used customer save after" that's whay i have asked

Comment: Yes I have tried it but at that time it was not working so i used second solution by override controller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by observer.

**SR/StackExchange/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="sr_customer_account_createPost" instance="SR\StackExchange\Observer\CustomerRegisterSuccess" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**SR/StackExchange/Observer/CustomerRegisterSuccess.php**

```
namespace SR\StackExchange\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class CustomerRegisterSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    /** @var CustomerRepositoryInterface */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Manages redirect
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $accountController = $observer->getAccountController();
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $request = $accountController->getRequest();
        $customer_number = $request->getParam('customer_number');
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('customer_number', $customer_number);
        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
    }
}
```

**NB:** here **'customer_number'** is custom attribute

Comment: how do we get customer id here please reply me thanks

Comment: @SohelRana: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::save() must implement interface Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface