# Magento 2 How can I add State and Country attribute for customer account information in AdminSide?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, country-regions

How can I achieve State and Country field functionality in Admin under **customer Account Information**?

In the customer account information section, how to add country and state fields and state is rendering accordingly country-wise as per address information.

[image: Country]

I need to achieve state list if options are available and text field if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="country_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="region">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">State/Region</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
                    <item name="customEntry" xsi:type="string">region</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filterBy" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">${ $.provider }:${ $.parentScope }.country_id</item>
                        <item name="field" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Let me know if you facing any issues.**

**Thanks.**

Comment: can you have any reference for save this data in admin form? @RonakRathod

Comment: You Can use customer_save_before event and save the custom field value

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/223676/72911

Comment: Thank you @RonakRathod

Comment: Welcome... @Charmi